# Last block incomplete in decryption - Android Studio JAVA

Tags: java, android-studio, encryption

I have a password field. I want to encrypt and decrypt it.

So when inserting in SQLite, encrypt than when reading out, decrypt it.

I followed the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kN8hlHO8US0 tutorial.

My encrypting is working. But my decryption is not working.

I have a list of admins. When I tap one, I want to see their password (decrypted).

The code below sends the (encrypted string) password to mSyncAdminsDatabaseHelper which as got a method decrypt().

```
            String placedecrypt = mSyncAdminsDatabaseHelper.decrypt(place.toString());

            Toast.makeText(ViewAdmins.this, placedecrypt, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

on mSyncAdminsDatabaseHelper, I have following code.

```
//set key
private SecretKey generateKey(String password) throws Exception {
    final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] bytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    byte[] key = digest.digest();
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    return secretKey;
}

//encrypt
private String encrypt(String password) throws Exception {
    SecretKey key = generateKey(password);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encval = c.doFinal(password.getBytes());
    String encryptedValue = Base64.encodeToString(encval, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encryptedValue;
}

//decrypt
public String decrypt(String password) throws Exception {
    SecretKey key = generateKey(password);
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    byte[] encval = c.doFinal(password.getBytes());
    byte[] encryptedValue = Base64.decode(encval, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String decryptedvalue = new String(encryptedValue);
    return decryptedvalue;
}
```

**I get below error**

```
W/System.err: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:1143)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1736)
W/System.err:     at com.example.photoapp.SyncAdminsDatabaseHelper.decrypt(SyncAdminsDatabaseHelper.java:182)
        at com.example.photoapp.SyncAdminsDatabaseHelper.test(SyncAdminsDatabaseHelper.java:190)
        at com.example.photoapp.ViewAdmins$1.onItemClick(ViewAdmins.java:100)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:350)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1683)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:4094)
W/System.err:     at android.widget.AbsListView$10.run(AbsListView.java:6583)
```

Comment: You need to base64-decode the ciphertext _before_ decrypting, not the plaintext after. Also: Cipher `"AES"` in Java defaults the mode of operation (wee wikipedia) to ECB, which is mostly insecure and should almost never be used, although in this case using a single unsalted hash of a password as key is much _more_ insecure. And, encrypting _and decrypting_ a password _with itself_ (or rather its own hash) is insane; you need the password in clear at all endpoints, so the encrypted version is completely worthless and cannot provide any benefit ever. ...

Comment: ... If this password is for logging-in to your system, you should not encrypt at all, you should store an irreversible (but reproducible) hash _designed for password hashing_ NOT a simple data hash; see security.SX and crypto.SX for _lots_ of Qs on this topic. If this password is for something else, either get someone with security experience or training involved, or articulate your requirements clearly and search or ask on security.SX.